# setValue of filtered row cell in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for some guidance with a Google Apps Script I'm trying to write.

I have a Google Sheet containing thousands of links. I need to check if the links are still 'Active' and if not marked them as 'Closed'. To save iterating over every single row I'm first filtering the rows to get all of the links that have 'Active' set in `row[9]`. I'm then using fetch to get the response code and based on that code update the value of `row[9]` to either 'Still Active' or 'Closed'

I know I can use as a concept in any other case:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sites").getRange().setValue();`

However, I'm finding it difficult to use this in conjunction with the `filteredRows` I need.

The sheet looks a little like this:

```
| date       | name     | link                      | status |
|------------|--------- |---------------------------|--------|
| 2021-08-24 | Google   | https://www.google.com/   | Active |
| 2021-08-20 | Facebook | https://www.facebook.com/ | Active |
| 2021-08-18 | Twitter  | https://www.twitter.com/  | Closed |
```

Current script:

```js
function getStatus() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites");
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var filteredRows = rows.filter(function (row) {
        var status = row[9];
        if (status === "Active") {
            return row
        }
    });

    filteredRows.forEach(function(row){

        var link = row[3];
        var status = row[9];
        var options = {
            'muteHttpExceptions': true,
            'followRedirects': false,
            'validateHttpsCertificates': false
        };
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options);

        if (status === "Active") {

            if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
              
              row.status.setValue("Still Active!");
              
            }
            else {
              row.status.setValue("Closed!");
            }
            
         }

    })
}
```

Comment: You should try using a library like sheetfu app scripts so things are cleaner: https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu-apps-script. Your use case would then be quite straight forward.

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo unable to share the sheet but supplied an example of the layout. Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to use one more array `indexes` that will contain positions of filtered rows:

```
var indexes = [];
var filteredRows = rows.filter(function (row, i) {
        var status = row[9];
        if (status === "Active") {
            indexes.push(i);
            return row;
        }
    });
```

Then you can change the rows in your main array this way:

```
indexes.forEach((x,i) => rows[x][9] = filteredRows[i].status);
```

But actually I don't understand why do you need to filter the rows? You can just skip the rows that have no 'Active' in column [9].

Or you're trying to use `setValues()` for every processed row? It's a really bad idea if you have thousands rows. You need to process the 2d array (a whole) and set all the thousands rows at once:

```
sheet.getDataRange().setValues(rows);
```

So after all your code could look like this:

```
function getStatus() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites");
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'followRedirects': false,
    'validateHttpsCertificates': false
  };

  for (let i in rows) {
    if (rows[i][9] != 'Active') continue; // skip the row if not 'Active'

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rows[i][3], options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) { 
      rows[i][9] = "Still Active!";
    } else { 
      rows[i][9] = "Closed!";
    }

  }

  sheet.getDataRange().getValues(rows); // set all values back to the sheet
}
```

Though, if you have thousands rows the script can excess the time limit. It will need another tricks then.

Probably it will work. Slowly (due `setValue()` for every changed row) but you can run it several times:

```
function getStatus() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites");
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var indexes = [];
  
  var filteredRows = rows.filter(function (row, i) {
    var status = row[9];
    if (status === "Active") {
      indexes.push(i+1); // save the index of filtered row
      return row;
    }
  });

  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'followRedirects': false,
    'validateHttpsCertificates': false
  };

  filteredRows.forEach(function (row, i) {

    var link = row[3];
    var status = row[9];
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      sheet.getRange(indexes[i],10).setValue("Still Active!");
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(indexes[i],10).setValue("Closed!");
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Does the job nicely and I don't mind running 2-3 times :)